# Logistic regression ValueError - inconsistent numbers of samples, but values are of equal length

Tags: python, pandas, regression, logistic-regression

I am trying to run a logistic regression model. My variables are:

`X_train` - pandas df of size (13, 16110) and  `y_train` - list of length (16110)

When running the logistic regression model below, I receive the following error:
 `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [13, 16110]`

As my data is the same length, I cannot see why such an error is occurring. Should it be the case I should be using a pandas series of length (,16110)?

Edit: I realise this may be a duplicate question but others did not seem to address this exact problem where data seems to be of the same length

```
 def logisticRegression(X_train, y_train):  

    logistic = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
    pipeline = Pipeline( [('scl', StandardScaler()),('pca', PCA(n_components=2)), ('clf', logistic)] )
    param_grid= [dict( pca__n_components=[None, 2, 3, 4, 5], clf__C = [0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100,1000]  )]
    grid_search= GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid = param_grid)
    grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

    return(grid_search.best_estimator_, grid_search.best_score_)
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a numpy array from `y_train`?

Comment: @oriolmirosa I just tried there, got an array of (16110,). Still gives the same error.

Comment: Looking at this more closely, it does look like you have an inconsistent number of samples. Your X_train should be of shape [16110, 13]. If you have a DataFrame, transpose it (i.e., `X_train.T`) and try again.

Comment: @oriolMirosa Thank you very much. That is exactly it. I would have never noticed.